# Rewrite rule causing a loop

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We have an online shop with a welcome page. Our SEO company has asked us to get rid of the welcome page with a rewrite as follows. i am struggling to get this to work. Can you help please?

rewrite www.domain.co.uk/catalog/index.php to become www.domain.co.uk, then 301 from www.domain.co.uk/catalog/index.php to www.domain.co.uk.

I have the following code which causes a redirect loop and nothing is displayed

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ catalog/index.php [L]
Redirect 301 /catalog/index.php http://www.domain.co.uk
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How's that?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /catalog/
RewriteRule .* / [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?$ catalog/index.php [L]
```

If *catalog* is part of the browser request, a 301 will correctly *redirect* to /, which in turn will *rewrite* to catalog/index.php.

Comment: Then I don't understand your problem. I thought catalog/index.php should disappear as such - how can it be duplicate content when it is moved SEOwise by a 301?

Comment: Sorry, let me explain it a better way:-
I need to be able to make it so that when someone visits my site at say:

a) http://www.mysite.co.uk/

It actually displays the content from:

b) http://www.mysite.co.uk/catalog/index.php

and also if a user types in (b) then they are 301'd to (a)

What your example does is the redirection but not the rewrite